# std::cout::setf doesn't work (setf to hex)

Tags: c++

I tested code in the book "Practical C++ Programming".
But following example doesn't work as book says.
What am I missing? Please help.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number = 0x3FF;
    std::cout << "Dec: " << number << '\n';
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex);
    std::cout << "Hex: " << number << '\n';

    std::cout.setf(std::ios::dec);
}
```

The expected result was

```
Dec: 1023
Hex: 3ff
```

But, I got

```
Dec: 1023
Dec: 1023
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that you can simply do `std::cout << std::ios::hex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [the second overload of `setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) that clears base flags with the `std::ios::basefield` mask:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);

Dec: 1023
Hex: 3ff
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/5caBsS)